# SET jQuery returned value to PHP variable

Tags: php, jquery

I need to set value returned from jQuery Success function to the variable in PHP page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url : 'test.php',
            type : 'POST',
            data : $('form').serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                $('#hiddenField').html(data);
       }

<?php
    $phpVariable = “hiddenfield value” --- returned from test.php
?>
```

Please note: I want the returned value in PHP variable only and on the same page. However I can set the value an hidden variable, but not able to get value and assign to PHP variable from an hidden field

Comment: what you suppose to do, with that value ?

Comment: My test.php does some calculation and return a total amount back to jQuery success function. Now I want this returned value to be calculated (PHP code) further and want to send to another form.

Answer (score 1):

echo that `$phpVariable`then `data` should contain that variable

Answer (score 0):

The PHP runs first, on the *server*, and the JavaScript runs afterwards in the *client* browser. You can't mix those two, because they are two different programs which run at different times.

Here is the order of events:

1. The PHP code is run to generate the HTML document (including inline script tags) on the server, which is then sent to the browser.
2. The HTML document gets sent to the user. It has *no* PHP in it anymore. You can verify this by viewing the page source in your browser.
3. The document and all of its resources, including external scripts, get loaded by the client's browser.
4. Only then does the JavaScript run; and the AJAX call presumably happens sometime later on.

If you want to pass data from your JavaScript code (client) to your PHP code (server), you'll have to include it in the AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language, and it doesn't wait for javascript (client side language), to capture the values.

Not sure, but probably you need to do something in php itself with that value, and you can do it in same ajax call (in `test.php`), and return the result as view which you need to display to user.